# Why is the string loop is being ignored?

Tags: c, string, loops, split

I am new to the programming world and I'm trying to make a string split by using a loop that should split all characters separately but it's being ignored and basically ends with showing the input of the user instead of using the loop to separate the individual letters/characters. Have I missed declaring something important in the loop?

Comment: People are more likely to find this question if you tag the language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++);` <- there's a semicolon here, so your loop literally does nothing

also note that `str[i] != '\0'` is a very dangerous way of iterating your string. If your string doesn't contain a zero-terminal character, C will happily continue reading memory beyond the end.

Comment: `strlen(str)` will loop over `str` until it finds a null terminator. So there's really no difference between that and doing it manually. Unless you have `i < strlen(str)` as the loop condition in which case you've just made your loop `O(n*n)` instead of `O(n)`

Comment: I guess you're correct on that one. You could always go with `sizeof(str)`, but that *will* include `\0`. Long story short, C and strings are still not friends.

Comment: It depends on what you want. `sizeof(str)` returns the number of bytes that `str` takes up, which in this case is 50. `strlen(str)` is the length of the C-style string `str`. Since `fgets` was used `str` *will* be a C-style string, i.e. it will have a null terminator. Just call `strlen(str)` once outside of the loop to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are few syntactical errors with what you posted.

```
 /* This should be <stdio.h>
 ... 
 /* Don't need a. semi-colon here
 int main();
 ...
 /* Calling getchar() will cause you to lose the first character of the
    the input
 */ 
    getchar();
    ... 
 /* Don't need a semi-colon here */
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++
    ...
    system("pause");
 }
```

With those adjustments you should find the code works.

```
Write text:
Hello world
Input: Hello world

H
e
l
l
o

w
o
r
l
d


sh: pause: command not found
```

I'm not on windows, so if the code on your end does not seem to work after making adjustments it is probably windows specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using java, you can just split with an empty string and then loop through the list that's created from the split method.